# How to select an element value from one XML and generate a new XML with different tag name using XSL?

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<max:InvokePMR_SR_OS xmlns:max="http://www.ibbm.com/maximo"
 creationDateTime="2008-09-28T21:49:45" baseLanguage="string" transLanguage="string"
 messageID="string" maximoVersion="string">
 <max:PMR_SR_OSSet>
  <max:SR action="Delete" relationship="string" deleteForInsert="string" transLanguage="string">
   <max:MAXINTERRORMSG>string</max:MAXINTERRORMSG>
   <max:CLASS maxvalue="string" changed="true">string</max:CLASS>
   <max:DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION changed="true">string</max:DESCRIPTION_LONGDESCRIPTION>
   <max:TICKETID changed="true">abc123def</max:TICKETID>
  </max:SR>
 </max:PMR_SR_OSSet>
</max:InvokePMR_SR_OS>
```

I want to pick the value of TICKETID which is abc123def and generate a new XML like below
Output XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<pmrtext>abc123def</pmrtext>
```

Please help me to get a valid XSL file which will convert my input XML into output XML.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. If you add code, mark it and press the `{}` button.

Answer (score 1):

This transformation should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:max="http://www.ibbm.com/maximo">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <xsl:template match="max:TICKETID">
        <xsl:element name="pmrtext">
            <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="//max:TICKETID"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following xsl will do the job for you:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:max="http://www.ibbm.com/maximo" version="1.0"> 
<!-- declare your input xml's namespace -->
  <xsl:template match="/max:InvokePMR_SR_OS/max:PMR_SR_OSSet/max:SR"> 
  <!-- xpath your way to your element -->
    <xsl:element name="pmrtext"> <!-- your element name here -->
      <xsl:value-of select="max:TICKETID"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I guess the tricky part would be declaring the namespace of your input xml. Other than that it is pretty straight-forward.

There are many ways in which you can reach the value of the desired element through xpath, this is just one.